# How to check if authorization header exists in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to catch requests without authorization header in Nginx and redirect it to a different path.

```
server {
    ...

    location @authorized {

            if($http_authorization){
                // Do stuff
            }
    }
}
```

This is what I get when I run nginx -t

> nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "if($http_authorization)"

The header seems to be in place as when I try to debug using this in the place of the above if I get the header back.

```
add_header 'X-myheader' '$http_authorization' always;
return 418;
```

Comment: You need a space between the `if` and the `(`.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks. I feel so stupid now. I wasted hours on this...